# loop all videos from folder to rtmp stream

Tags: ffmpeg

I am bash user and I want to loop all videos from folder to rtmp, one video at a time. I am facing issue of stream stop after a 1st video finished  I need continuous rtmp after finished 1st video and jump to next video. I am using following codes:

```
for j in *.mp4;
    do
        ffmpeg -threads 2 -re -fflags +genpts  -i $j -i '/c/Users/user/Desktop/ffmpeg_logo/mylogo.png' -filter_complex 'overlay=W-w-50:H-h-25' -ac 2 -f flv -vcodec libx264 -profile:v baseline -b:v 2000k -maxrate 2000k -bufsize 2000k -r 24 -ar 44100 -g 48 -c:a aac -b:a 64k  "rtmp://user:passwd@ip:1935/live/mystream"  

    done
```

Answer (score 4):

You could do this by looping over the videos in a subshell, and piping to another copy of `ffmpeg` to generate the RTMP stream. For example:

```
(for j in *.mp4; do
    ffmpeg -threads 2 -re -fflags +genpts -i $j \
        -i '/c/Users/user/Desktop/ffmpeg_logo/mylogo.png' -filter_complex 'overlay=W-w-50:H-h-25' \
        -vcodec libx264 -profile:v baseline -b:v 2000k -r 24 -maxrate 2000k -bufsize 2000k  \
        -ac 2 -ar 44100 -g 48 -c:a aac -b:a 64k \
        -f mpegts -
done) | ffmpeg -f mpegts -i - -c copy -bsf:a aac_adtstoasc -f flv rtmp://user:password@ip:1935/live/mystream
```

Notice the brackets around the `for` loop; that creates a subshell to run the first read & encode `ffmpeg` command. The output from that command is sent over the `stdout` ("standard output") [pipe](https://bash.cyberciti.biz/guide/Pipes) to the input of the second `ffmpeg` command, which generates the RTMP stream. The syntax for that is using `-` as the name of the input or output file.

I've had to include a [bitstream filter](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-bitstream-filters.html#aac_005fadtstoasc) `aac_adtstoasc` because I've used an [MPEG Transport Stream](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MPEG_transport_stream) as the format on the pipe as well.